# WebServices/SOAP for C++

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, axis2c

I've spent so many time trying to find a good Open Source tool to integrate webservices with c/c++.

- GSOAP: I cant use it because the license, if you use its tool to generate code by the WSDL, GPL license is not avaiable.
- WWSAPI: Appart that is only for Windows, if you read documentation carefully, when you need the redistributables, you have to mail to a Microsoft email, so, I think I should have to pay too.
- Axis2C: Project is not maintained (at all) and if you want to use the wsdl to code tool, you are going to get into a lot of memory leaks.

Reading other posts here, someone was speaking about axis2c but using SVC Client API instead of generating code tool. I am using it, and it works, but my question is, it is worth to use SVC Client API, instead of developing your own socket setting the envelope before the xml? I'm not an SOAP expert, could SVC Client API save me time? Its AXIS2c with SVC Client API hiding me more WebServices concepts that I should implement if I make manually?

Thanks in advance!